# Is it expected behavior that a file path throws an exception when used as a key in a ApplicationDataContainer

Tags: c#, windows-8, .net-4.5

I tried to use a file path (just a string) as a key in a ApplicationDataContainer and it fails. There are 3 different problems:

1. The container will report a key exists even if it doesn't, if the key is a file path
2. If you try to add a key that is a file path that does exist, it doesn't do anything.
3. If you try to add a key that is a file path that doesn't exist it throws an exception:

Has anyone seen an issue like this, and is this expected behavior? I can't find any documentation that says files paths as keys are invalid, and it seems very strange to me for MS to be trying to take what is a random string as far as they know and treating it like a file path.

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll

 WinRT information: Error trying to query the application data container item info

 Additional information: The specified path is invalid.
```

Example code:

```
var container = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.CreateContainer("SomeContainerName", ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
if (container.Values.ContainsKey("C:\\Some_Fake_Path") == false) // This will report as true even though the key is not in the container
      {
        //If you try to run this line it throws an exception that file can not be found even though it is just a key value pair
        container.Values.Add("C:\\Some_Fake_Path", "SomeStuffHere");

        //This line won't throw, but it won't actually add a key/value pair either
        container.Values.Add("C:\\This_Path_Actually_Exists\\SomeFile.txt", "SomeStuffHere");
      }
```

Comment: When I run your code it runs fine for me. The only time it fails is if I try to add the same value more than once (which makes sense to me).

Comment: Strange, I just double checked and mine is still doing it. I'm using VS 2012 Ultimate on Windows 8 x64, what are you running?

Comment: Win 8 x64, VS 2012 Pro